# Error after migrating net core preview xproj to csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, .net-core

I developed a net core class library using Net Core "1.0.0-preview2-003131" version. Currently using VS2015.
But as this should be released soon, I want to move it to "1.0.1". 
I installed this update: .NET Core 1.0.4 (https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases/tag/1.0.4)

When I change the version in my global.json I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   MSB4019 The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

So I read that doing "dotnet migrate" it changes my project from xproj to csproj, and the problem should be solved.

But doing that, my csproj doesn't load properly, showing error:

> The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

Comment: you need to upgrade your aspnetcore version on package.json

Comment: To migrate you'll need Visual Studio 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migration/

Comment: @ahmar I have no package.json and this is a class library, not an asp net core project

Comment: @trydis mmm is there a way of using an official release of net core in VS2015?

Comment: Forget about VS2015. If you cannot get VS2017, use Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @trydis Wrong. You can do migrate without VS, you need only .Net Core SDK in proper version

Comment: @J.Doe: Sure, but he's using VS 2015, that won't work. If he wants to continue using VS "full", no other choice than 2017. The last error he shows is when trying to load a migrated project using VS 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 to use the csproj format that dotnet-migrate generates. .NET Core CLI does not support xproj or project.json.

Or, you can use Visual Studio Code with the C# extension on either project.json or csproj projects, but not both.